# develop of a bash backup.sh for rsync between linux and cygwin

Tags: bash, cron, rsync, backup, cygwin

i work on a debian 10 server with ispconfig 3 the backups files is in `/var/backup/web*/*"Today"*`. (exemple : `/var/backup/web30/db_c1gifts_2020-07-25_00-07.sql.gz`

i install cygwin on my windows 10.

i would like to know where is the fault in my backup.sh (after i will create a crontab in cygwin)

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d");
rsync -azvr -e 'sshpass -p "myloginpasswd" ssh -p 1505 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' mylogin@myhost.com:"/var/backup/web*/*'${now}'*"  /cygdrive/g/var/var-backup-${now}
```

at this time, if i try this command line i receive an error

```
rsync: change_dir "/var/backup/web*" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 8 bytes  received 88 bytes  192.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1805) [Receiver=3.2.0dev]
```

but this command line works:

```
rsync -azvr -e 'sshpass -p "myloginpasswd" ssh -p 1505 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' mylogin@myhost.com:/var/backup/web*/*  /cygdrive/g/var/var-backup-${now}
```

but i receive all files.

Comment: check the ` ' ` usage . '${now}' will not be expanded

Comment: @matzeri Single quoted variable inside double quote will be expanded. But it will print the single quote aswell

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to replace this

```
"/var/backup/web*/*'${now}'*"
```

by `"/var/backup/web*/*${now}*"`

it works perfect